# python.defaultInterpreterPath in VS Code's settings.json shows "unknown configuration setting"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

The old `python.pythonPath` has been deprecated in the latest `vscode` 1.64.1 and replaced by `python.defaultInterpreterPath`. However, when I set it in `projectname/.vscode/settings.json`, it is greyed and shown a popup as:

> unknown configuration setting

This still persists even after restarting VS Code.

Anyone can shed some light on this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be solved now, or just remember to avoid using the "settings" key again, within a `settings.json` file, but a single dict, eg:

```
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"
}
```

Comment: Also note, when working on a remote, the relevant `settings.json` is in `.vscode-server/data/Machine/`. Similarly, when using `code-server` in a JupyterHub server, it is in `.local/share/code-server/Machine/`.