# Make venv default terminal for Project in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project in VSCode 1.86.2 on Windows 10 where it used to open terminals with venv automatically activated. Very handy.

It stopped working and I have not been able to turn this feature back on. There is no associated error message.

**Setup**

My pseudo path is like:

A pseudo path looks like:

```
C/
├─ Users/
├─ AlGrant/
│  ├─ test_pyrtlsdr/ 
│  │  ├─ .vscode/
│  │  │  ├─ settings.json
│  │  ├─ .venv/
│  │  │  ├─ Scripts/
│  │  │  │  ├─ python.exe
│  │  ├─ src/
```

**Answers Searched**

**#1**

I have tried to reactivate this feature by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433333/auto-activate-virtual-environment-in-visual-studio-code) which called for me to edit `settings.json` in `.vscode` directory and to add:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
```

or the second answer suggested:

```
"settings": {
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/venv/bin/python"
}
```

or even :

```
{
"python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "~/venv/bin/python"
}
```

Neither of those options worked. I presume on windows the path should be written : "/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" instead of bin? (which I tried)

**#2**

Another [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116255/python-defaultinterpreterpath-in-vs-codes-settings-json-shows-unknown-configur) stated that the setting should be :

```
    {
       "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"
    }
```

Again I also tried :

```
    {
       "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python"
    }
```

**#3**

And yet another [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225994/json-setting-path-for-python-in-visual-studio-code) suggested setting it vai the settings cog (bottom right):

[image]

And I added it like:

[image]

I note this settings file is located in the AppData\Roaming\Code\User folder (not project folder).

**Does venv work**

I have confirmed that I can manually activate the venv from command prompt - so thats not broken.

I note that the bottom right of VSCode suggests that it is using venv:

[image]

How can I have new terminals in VSCode activate the venv?

Answer (score 2):

It appears this feature has been removed from the latest version of the VSCode Python plugin.

You can still check what evenv you are in by hovering over the terminal.

[image]

It has been raised as an issue here : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22917

And Further information about how to check which venv your in is here : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Activate-Environments-in-Terminal-Using-Environment-Variables

Comment: Interesting. I recently made an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/23008) similar to this and thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue and found that if you execute `which python` on your terminal window, you can validate which interpreter is being used (global or venv).

It's not as visual or friendly, but hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35837052)